# How can I communicate between classes in a Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, class, xamarin

How is it possible to communicate between two classes?
I have two classes, one is a stopwatch class and my second is my lifecircle events class "App"

class1:

```
public partial class Stopwatch : ContentPage
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch;
        bool isOn = false;
        public Stopwatch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            labeltimer.Text = "00:00:00.00";
        }

        private void btnTimerReset(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "Start";
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }

        private void btnTimerstop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (labeltimer.Text != "00:00:00.00")
                btnStart.Text = "Resume";
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        private void btnTimerStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timerstart();
            isOn = true;
        }

        private void Timerstart()
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), () =>
            {
                labeltimer.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ff");
                return true; // return true to repeat counting, false to stop timer
            });
        }
       public bool isStopwatchEnabled()
        {

            if(isOn)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

App Class

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        bool isenableSW = false;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
            {
                
            };
        }
        protected override void OnSleep()
        {

            Stoppuhr tp = new Stoppuhr();
             isenableSW = tp.isStopwatchEnabled();

            if (isenablesw)
            {
                
                tp.Timerstart();

               
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is now, when I start my stopwatch my bool variable switches from false to true. That is what I want... when I trigger now the onSleep() function, it creates a new instance of my stopwatch class and next it should check if the stopwatch was enabled before onSleep() triggered, but my bool variable is always false because it has its standard value(= false). Makes sense... but how can I communicate between these classes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a solution. The value doesn't change when I do this:

```
bool isOn = false -> static bool isOn = false;
```